# Is it possible to customize Wagtail's auth forms?

Tags: wagtail

This page shows how to customize templates: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/admin_templates.html

But I want to customize the forms instead. I'm trying to add reCaptcha to all of them.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Wagtail provides a Django setting called [`WAGTAILADMIN_USER_LOGIN_FORM`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/settings.html#wagtailadmin-user-login-form) which allows a custom form to be declared for the login form.

Wagtail does not provide a setting for the password reset workflow though unfortunately.

##### **`settings/base.py`**

```py
WAGTAILADMIN_USER_LOGIN_FORM = 'app.forms.CustomLoginForm'
```

##### **`forms.py`**

```py
from django import forms
from wagtail.admin.forms.auth import LoginForm


class CustomLoginForm(LoginForm):
    captcha = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

A reminder that there is a way to work with [custom User models](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/custom_user_models.html) in Wagtail which may also suit your customisation needed.